# A proof about $\sigma$-algebras via transfinite induction

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

*This is a proofreading question.*

---

I was trying to help out on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354600/measurable-projection-theorem) and in the course of that I encountered the following assertion:

> Let $(X, \mathcal A)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B)$ be $\sigma$-algebras, and let $(X\times Y, \mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B)$ be their product $\sigma$-algebra. Denote by $\pi_X$ the projection $X \times Y \to X$.
>
> Then for any $S \in \mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$, the set $\forall_\pi(S) := \{x \in X \mid \forall y \in Y: (x,y) \in S\}$ is measurable.

Now we know that $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B = \sigma(\mathcal A \times \mathcal B)$, and the latter may be constructed from $\mathcal A \times \mathcal B$ by transfinite induction on $\aleph_1$, as set out in $\S 3$ of [this paper](http://www.swansonsite.com/W/instructional/transind.pdf).

Thus we can verify that the assertion above holds by transfinite induction, starting at the generators $\mathcal A \times \mathcal B$ (for which it is trivial) and establishing "closure of the assertion" under countable union and complement (and countable intersection, if you like to "speed things up"). Verification at limit ordinals is trivial.

---

Now this outline seems to prove the assertion. The problem I have is that the source for [ref'd question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354600/measurable-projection-theorem), *Set-valued analysis* by Aubin-Frankowska, states with regard to the there-requested theorem:

> It is quite tempting to think that the projection [...] of a Borel set should be still a Borel set. [...] The discovery of Borel sets whose continuous image is not Borel started the intensive study of *analytic sets*, i.e., continuous images of Borel sets. [...]

and references *Convex analysis and measurable multifunctions* by Castaing, where a very technical and non-illuminating proof is given that I don't understand at the moment. But in mathematics chat, I and @Vrouvrou have reduced this "Measurable Projection Theorem" to a special case of above asssertion.

---

I find it quite hard to believe that this approach would discard (part of) the motivation for a whole area of research (viz on *analytic sets*) and surpass a hard, technical proof. So, where is my mistake?

Comment: $\pi_X(S)=\{x \in X \mid \exists y \in Y: (x,y) \in S\}$.

Comment: @Michael Yes of course. How could that possibly be unclear?

Comment: That happens. [Projections can be tricky](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/projections-can-be-tricky/).

Comment: In general $\forall_\pi(S)\subsetneqq\pi_X[S]$.

Comment: @Brian I know. Rather, it is the largest set $A$ such that $A \times X \subseteq S$. This is in fact one of the reasons why I crafted the transfinite argument.

Comment: Then I don’t understand just what it is that you’re asking.

Comment: @Brian: The set $\forall_\pi(S)$ arises when proving that $\{S \in \mathcal A\otimes \mathcal B \mid \pi_X(S) \in \mathcal A\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (containing $\mathcal A \times \mathcal B$ hence equals the product $\sigma$-algebra), namely in showing closure under complement. I just want to know if my assertion is correct.

Comment: In the linked question the space is assumed to be *complete* so the authors' comment seems to point out that completeness can't be dropped from the hypotheses. Analytic sets are known to be [universally measurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set). // I assume that you tried to do something like $\forall_\pi(S) = [\pi_X(S^c)]^c$. So $\forall_\pi(S)$ is measurable for all $S \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ iff $\pi_X(S)$ is measurable for all $S \in \mathcal{A \otimes B}$.

Comment: If you have a proof that this assertion implies that every projection of a Borel set is Borel, you have a proof that the assertion is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: @Michael: I don't have such a proof (besides, such would be a highly unsatisfactory answer to any "is this proof correct"-type of question). In fact I don't quite see what Borel sets have to do with the Measurable Projection theorem since $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$ isn't even a topological space so doesn't _have_ Borel sets to begin with. Nonetheless they give this mysterious remark and refer to a highly technical proof.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any proof in your post which could be checked for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, there was an error. It is not surprising that none of the others were able to find it, because I hid it in the small phrase:

> *[...] establishing "closure of the assertion" under countable union [...]*

This is not true. Suppose we are at step $\alpha$, and we have a countable collection $(S_{\alpha,n})_{n \in \Bbb N}$ of sets in $\sigma_\alpha(\mathcal A \times \mathcal B)$. Then we can manipulate a bit as follows:

$$\forall_\pi\left(\bigcup S_{\alpha,n}\right) = \pi_X\left[\left(\bigcup S_{\alpha,n}\right)^c\right]^c = \pi_X \left[\bigcap S_{\alpha,n}^c\right]^c$$

but in general it may occur that e.g.:

$$\pi_X\left[\bigcap S_{\alpha,n}^c\right] \subsetneq \bigcap \pi_X[S_{\alpha,n}^c]$$

Thus this train of thought does not follow through.

---

Rather, while this was invented to prove that $\pi_X(S)\in \mathcal A \implies \pi_X(S^c) \in \mathcal A$, it becomes reasonable to believe that extra conditions on the measure spaces may be necessary. This is in fact in line with the observations made in the question statement.

Comment: Did you hide it intentionally? For see if others would find?

Comment: Well I didn't, but I can see where you're coming from, given how I phrased it. :)